# ¿Es posible desactivar el zoom de un mapa de Google Maps incrustado al pasar el scroll?

Tags: html, bootstrap, google-maps, scroll, zoom

Hola buenas noches a todos, sigo con mi proyecto en una institución de enseñanza y me he encontrado con un problema que espero me puedan ayudar a resolver. Utilizando Google Maps agregué un mapa al sitio web como se ve a continuación:
[image: Captura de cómo se ve el sitio con el mapa incrustado]

Incluyo el código que utilizo:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h2>¿Dónde nos encontramos?</h2>
    <hr>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h3 class="text-center text-muted">Texcoco</h3>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d15078.060297406828!2d-98.7672826!3d19.1289181!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xec6eed4489e6a338!2sSanta+Catalina+de+Siena+Amecameca!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2smx!4v1502307796735" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

El problema aquí es que cuando el usuario va bajando sobre la página, al llegar al mapa, este empieza a reducir el zoom debido al scroll haciendo la navegación y la ubicación de la institución algo difícil y molesto.

[image: Al pasar el scroll el mapa reduce el zoom]

Mi pregunta es, **¿Hay alguna forma de "desactivar" el zoom por scroll del mapa haciendo que sólo se pueda aumentar por los botones?**
Buscando en internet encontré que una posible solución sería utilizando la API de Google Maps para obtener un Mapa estático, pero para esto debo pagar una cuota para obtener una llave, me parece. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Stackoverflow se planteó la misma [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992498/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-zoom-on-embedded-google-maps?answertab=votes#tab-top). Hay muchisimas respuestas, la mayoría proponen deshabilitar los eventos de ratón en el `iframe` con CSS:

```
pointer-events: none
```

Lo bueno de esto es que lo puedes habilitar nuevamente con:

```
pointer-events: auto
```

La idea es que por defecto esten deshabilitados y al pinchar en el `iframe` se habiliten de nuevo para poder navegar por el mapa normalmente y al dejar el mapa se dehabiliten de nuevo.

Hay una de las respuestas que lo hace con jQuery de forma muy sencilla, este es el ejemplo con tu código (añado texto para poder hacer scroll y ver el funcionamiento):

```js
$('.embed-responsive').click(function() {
  $('.embed-responsive iframe').css("pointer-events", "auto");
});

$(".embed-responsive").mouseleave(function() {
  $('.embed-responsive iframe').css("pointer-events", "none");
});
```

```css
.embed-responsive iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="text-center">
  <h2>¿Dónde nos encontramos?</h2>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum itaque et ex odio earum minus, corrupti repudiandae fugiat est tenetur. Quos eum distinctio, numquam. Quisquam deserunt quibusdam quia qui ad, illo quasi dolorem cumque facere id. Sunt necessitatibus sit minima ipsam, facere perferendis dolores optio debitis voluptatibus. Cupiditate explicabo, itaque iure saepe temporibus impedit, officiis mollitia expedita corporis velit optio consectetur dolorem. Qui at corrupti voluptate debitis blanditiis atque, repellendus iusto! Molestias rerum fugiat suscipit, ratione! Eos cupiditate dolores reiciendis, libero sapiente explicabo. Blanditiis officiis ratione rerum non ipsum, delectus culpa quia doloribus eveniet itaque ex hic commodi consequuntur voluptatem.
  </p>
  <p>Hic harum velit accusantium a commodi pariatur optio saepe voluptatibus, enim assumenda obcaecati doloremque ex maxime nihil vero corporis maiores ad minus, minima molestias repudiandae odit. Ex quasi obcaecati animi quia praesentium laborum, provident consequuntur asperiores cupiditate facere? Rem voluptatem sunt sint mollitia eos ipsa in laudantium sed reprehenderit minus porro repudiandae illum quas, sapiente, cumque quo ipsum omnis ducimus nemo molestias. Modi ea consectetur eius incidunt, hic illo eum ipsam libero omnis explicabo iure sit sapiente illum aspernatur, odio minus aliquam quidem fugiat odit assumenda, voluptas, facere esse adipisci laborum. Nihil molestias, qui quod iure vitae, ipsa earum deleniti!</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h3 class="text-center text-muted">Texcoco</h3>
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d15078.060297406828!2d-98.7672826!3d19.1289181!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xec6eed4489e6a338!2sSanta+Catalina+de+Siena+Amecameca!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2smx!4v1502307796735"
        width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum itaque et ex odio earum minus, corrupti repudiandae fugiat est tenetur. Quos eum distinctio, numquam. Quisquam deserunt quibusdam quia qui ad, illo quasi dolorem cumque facere id. Sunt necessitatibus sit minima ipsam, facere perferendis dolores optio debitis voluptatibus. Cupiditate explicabo, itaque iure saepe temporibus impedit, officiis mollitia expedita corporis velit optio consectetur dolorem. Qui at corrupti voluptate debitis blanditiis atque, repellendus iusto! Molestias rerum fugiat suscipit, ratione! Eos cupiditate dolores reiciendis, libero sapiente explicabo. Blanditiis officiis ratione rerum non ipsum, delectus culpa quia doloribus eveniet itaque ex hic commodi consequuntur voluptatem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum itaque et ex odio earum minus, corrupti repudiandae fugiat est tenetur. Quos eum distinctio, numquam. Quisquam deserunt quibusdam quia qui ad, illo quasi dolorem cumque facere id. Sunt necessitatibus sit minima ipsam, facere perferendis dolores optio debitis voluptatibus. Cupiditate explicabo, itaque iure saepe temporibus impedit, officiis mollitia expedita corporis velit optio consectetur dolorem. Qui at corrupti voluptate debitis blanditiis atque, repellendus iusto! Molestias rerum fugiat suscipit, ratione! Eos cupiditate dolores reiciendis, libero sapiente explicabo. Blanditiis officiis ratione rerum non ipsum, delectus culpa quia doloribus eveniet itaque ex hic commodi consequuntur voluptatem.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, funciona muy bien al ejecutarla. Sin embargo no logro hacer que funcione en mi proyecto, ya modifiqué el CSS de mi proyecto, sin embargo al modificar el **jQuery** parece que no funciona adecuadamente. Sólo para estar seguro, para el CSS estoy cambiando la clase `embed-responsive iframe`, pero en el **jQuery** ¿Se puede agregar las funciones al final del documento? De antemano gracias por resolver mis dudas.

Comment: Si, puedes ponerlas al final. De hecho suele ser mejor ponerlas al final para asegurarse  que ha cargado la página, o ponerlas dentro de un `ready`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, efectivamente se pueden poner al final, me parece que el problema era más bien de la caché del navegador.

Comment: Perdón, creí que ya la habia marcado cómo resuelta. Muchas gracias por la ayuda a ambos :)